# Retrieving values from database using node and mssql

Tags: node.js, sql-server

Here's a simple script i made:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const sql = require('mssql');
const itens = getRecords();

async function getRecords(){
    let itensList = [];
    const cfg = {
      //config here
    };
    sql.connect(cfg, function(err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        let request = new sql.Request();
        request.query("<query here>", (err, result) => {
            if(err) console.log(err);
            itensList = result;
        });
        return itensList;
    });
}

async function getPrices(){
    try{
        console.log(itens)
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}

getPrices();
```

Everything works, but when the getPrices() function gets called, here's what's being logged:

```
Promise { undefined }
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`request.query` is being called, but `itenslist` is being returned before it can be assigned.

Basically, the order of what is happening is:

1. `request.query` is called, and starts running the query.
2. Since `request.query` is asynchronous, we move on to the next task - returning `itenlist`
3. `request.query` finishes running, and assigns `itenlist` the expected value after it has already been returned.

To get your desired functionality, I would recommend using callbacks (which node-mssql supports). Alternatively, you could use the `await` keyword. For instance:

```
var queryText = 'SELECT 1 AS Value';
var queryResults = await connection.query(queryText);
```